# Android setClipChildren(false) not working while setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

Tags: android

My Activity use android:hardwareAccelerated="true", I need to draw a blur shadow out of view bounds, so I used code :

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
setClipChildren(false);
```

to make Paint's BlurMaskFilter work.
then I found that setClipChildren(false) not work any more, unless I remove setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null).

How can I fix this?